# Overflow:hidden почему картинка выходит за рамки своего блока при наведении

Tags: html, css

```css
.main {
 background-color: transparent;
 width: auto;
 position: relative;
 height: 100%;

}

.center_content {
 padding: 0;
 background-color: #ebeced;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.container_itemlist {
 min-height: 200px;
 position: relative;
}
#item-list {
 max-width: 975px;
 /*margin-left: 0px;
 margin: 0 auto;*/
}
.hotellist {
 min-height: 578px;
}
.item {
 position: relative;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(41,51,57,.5);
 color: #37454d;
 background: #fff;
}
.item_wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
}
ol {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
}
.image-wrapper:before {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 padding-top: 100%;
}
.item_image {
 position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s;
    transition: -webkit-transform .3s;
    transition: transform .3s;
    transition: transform .3s,-webkit-transform .3s;
}
.image-area {
 padding: 8px 6px 8px 8px;
 width: 22.25%;
 float: left;
}
.image-wrapper {
 position: relative;
 line-height: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.image-wrapper:hover{
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
    transform: scale(1.05);
}
.image_gallery {
 top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s;
    transition: opacity .3s;
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
    background: 0;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0;
    border:0;
} 
.image_gallery:hover {
 opacity: 1;
}
.text_wrapper {
  left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 71.5%;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,transparent,rgba(0,0,0,.25) 60%,rgba(0,0,0,.75));
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,transparent,rgba(0,0,0,.25) 60%,rgba(0,0,0,.75));
}
.image_text {
  color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: normal;
    padding-top: 16px;
    font-size: 14px;
    bottom: 8px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="center_content">
    <div class="container_itemlist">
      <section id="item-list">
        <ol class="hotellist">
          <li class="item-order">
            <article class="item">
              <div class="item_wrapper">
                <div class="image-area">
                  <div class="image-wrapper">
                    <img src="http://imgec.trivago.com/itemimages/44/39/443961_v1_isq.jpeg" class="item_image">
                    <button type="button" class="image_gallery">
                      <span class="text_wrapper">
                        <span class="image_text">View images</span>
                      </span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </article>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Почему при наведении картинка выходит за рамки блока.Мне нужно чтобы он увеличивался внутри блока [как показано тут](http://beloweb.ru/demo/uvimg/#) а не выходил за рамки блока.В  родительском элементе `Overflow hidden` указал правильно незнаю что я делаю не так .Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что скалить нужно то, что внутри контейнера `item_image`, а не сам контейнер `image_wrapper`.

зы: Поскольку кнопка у вас должна быть поверх картинки, то в рабочем варианте наведение должно быть на кнопку, чтобы картинка увеличилась. Поменяйте их кнопку и картинку местами в html, тогда можно будет задать селектор в css - `button:hover + img {}`.

```css
.main {
 background-color: transparent;
 width: auto;
 position: relative;
 height: 100%;

}

.center_content {
 padding: 0;
 background-color: #ebeced;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.container_itemlist {
 min-height: 200px;
 position: relative;
}
#item-list {
 max-width: 975px;
 /*margin-left: 0px;
 margin: 0 auto;*/
}
.hotellist {
 min-height: 578px;
}
.item {
 position: relative;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(41,51,57,.5);
 color: #37454d;
 background: #fff;
}
.item_wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
}
ol {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
}
.image-wrapper:before {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 padding-top: 100%;
}
.item_image {
 position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s;
    transition: -webkit-transform .3s;
    transition: transform .3s;
    transition: transform .3s,-webkit-transform .3s;
}
.image-area {
 padding: 8px 6px 8px 8px;
 width: 22.25%;
 float: left;
}
.image-wrapper {
 position: relative;
 line-height: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.image_gallery:hover + .item_image {
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
    transform: scale(1.05);
}
.image_gallery {
 top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s;
    transition: opacity .3s;
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
    background: 0;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0;
    border:0;
    z-index: 100;
} 
.image_gallery:hover {
 opacity: 1;
}
.text_wrapper {
  left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 71.5%;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,transparent,rgba(0,0,0,.25) 60%,rgba(0,0,0,.75));
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,transparent,rgba(0,0,0,.25) 60%,rgba(0,0,0,.75));
}
.image_text {
  color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: normal;
    padding-top: 16px;
    font-size: 14px;
    bottom: 8px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="center_content">
    <div class="container_itemlist">
      <section id="item-list">
        <ol class="hotellist">
          <li class="item-order">
            <article class="item">
              <div class="item_wrapper">
                <div class="image-area">
                  <div class="image-wrapper">
                    <button type="button" class="image_gallery">
                      <span class="text_wrapper">
                        <span class="image_text">View images</span>
                      </span>
                    </button>
                    <img src="http://imgec.trivago.com/itemimages/44/39/443961_v1_isq.jpeg" class="item_image">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </article>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо @Andrey Fedorov благодарю

Answer (score 0):

Задайте вашей картинке `transition: all 1s ease-out;`, а при наведении добавьте `transform: scale(1.1);`